# Error 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'Null' flutter web with null safety on

Tags: flutter

any suggestions how to debug null errors in flutter with null safety ?

> Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'Null'

just in case I replaced all Map<String, dynamic>  I have in my code with Map<String, dynamic>? but error continues

and thanks to the stupid way null safety is implemented the 675 lines of error stack(the one below is just the first 300) dos not contain a single one that contains information where in the Dart code the error originates.

I'm 99% sure the error is caused by a communication request but the error is happening before I get a response from my call to the server and is not even getting to a place to convert a Map object

unfortunately that is not the first time the new flutter NULL safety failed to provide a proper debug information with a NULL object error but so far I managed to fix them by reducing the executable code to the point of identifying the problem

```
Error: Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'Null'
at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:5054:11)
at Object.castError (http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:5013:15)
at Object.cast [as as] (http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:5336:17)
at Function.as_C [as as] (http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:4959:19)
at _engine.EngineSingletonFlutterWindow.new.handleNavigationMessage
(http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:173578:52)
at handleNavigationMessage.next (<anonymous>)
at runBody (http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:37456:34)
at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:37487:7)
at _engine.EngineSingletonFlutterWindow.new.handleNavigationMessage
(http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:173576:20)
at _engine.EnginePlatformDispatcher.__.[_sendPlatformMessage] (http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:161799:68)
at _engine.EnginePlatformDispatcher.__.sendPlatformMessage (http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:161627:33)
at _DefaultBinaryMessenger.[_sendPlatformMessage]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:2096:38)
at _DefaultBinaryMessenger.send
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:2138:40)
at OptionalMethodChannel._invokeMethod
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:937:50)
at _invokeMethod.next (<anonymous>)
at runBody (http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:37456:34)
at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:37487:7)
at OptionalMethodChannel.[_invokeMethod]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:935:20)
at OptionalMethodChannel.[_invokeMethod]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:1042:34)
at OptionalMethodChannel.invokeMethod
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:1038:36)
at invokeMethod.next (<anonymous>)
at runBody (http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:37456:34)
at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:37487:7)
at OptionalMethodChannel.invokeMethod
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:1037:20)
at Function.selectSingleEntryHistory
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/services/system_navigator.dart.lib.js:26:56)
at navigator$.NavigatorState.new.initState
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:24935:42)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:51379:54)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:51405:13)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:51398:27)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:51405:13)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:51398:27)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.SingleChildRenderObjectElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.SingleChildRenderObjectElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.SingleChildRenderObjectElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:44756:29)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.StatelessElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.SingleChildRenderObjectElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.SingleChildRenderObjectElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.SingleChildRenderObjectElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:44756:29)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:51405:13)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:51398:27)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:51405:13)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:51398:27)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at _InheritedNotifierElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at _InheritedNotifierElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at _InheritedNotifierElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at _InheritedNotifierElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at _InheritedNotifierElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at _InheritedNotifierElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:51405:13)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:51398:27)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:51405:13)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:51398:27)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.InheritedElement.new.mount
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30092:26)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.inflateWidget
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28926:16)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.updateChild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:28791:25)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30128:31)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.performRebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:51405:13)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.rebuild
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29263:12)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:30096:12)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.[_firstBuild]
(http://localhost:5000/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:51398:27)
at framework.StatefulElement.new.mount
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you are facing the error and ping?

Comment: Complaining about the information Dart gives you for your error and then turning to us *giving even less information* is kinda ironic, don't you think? Containing *zero* information on either your code or the error, this is not a question, it's just a rant.

Comment: I'm asking is there a special way of geting relevent information fron Flutter projects with null safty, before I moved the projet to null safty all errors contained the dart file and the line of code that error started, now that is not the case when the error is caused by a Null value

Comment: and sorry, can't share the code because I do not know where the error is, if I new at least the file where it is hapening I will fix it
the error shows after a succesfull call to server is made and before a succesfull responce is received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a solution to the problem does not exist, the debugger will not provide relevant information for the origins (the dart file) of the error.

But thankfully the particular problem is only in the latest version of the DEV channel (Flutter 2.3.0-16.0.pre & Dart 2.14.0 (build 2.14.0-136.0.dev)) and all works fine in the master channel so I no longer need a proper (usable) stack trace from the debugger to fix it.

special "thanks" to nvoigt for the "help", next time read before you comment.